# mergeMap function is giving error in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic3

ERROR:  `AngularFireObject <{}>` is not assignable to type `ObservableInput<{}>`

[image]
This is the sample function code

```
getAuthenticatedUserProfile(){

return this.auth.authState
    .map(user => user.uid)
    .mergeMap(authId => this.afDatabase.object('/profile/'+authId))
    .take(1)
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use pipe operator, which will allow to chain Observables.                        
                                                                                                                                
 return this.auth.authState.pipe(
    map(user => user.uid),
    mergeMap(authId => this.afDatabase.object('/profile/'+authId)),
    take(1))
}

Comment: The below answer solved it. Thanks once more!

Answer (score 3):

`mergeMap` expects the value to be returned of type `ObservableInput<{}>`. You're calling `this.afDatabase.object('/profile/'+authId)`, which is returning `AngularFireObject<{}>`

Calling `valueChanges()` will convert it to an observable:

```
return this.auth.authState
    .map(user => user.uid)
    .mergeMap(authId => this.afDatabase.object('/profile/'+authId).valueChanges())
    .take(1)
}
```